# Set Keyboard for Action in Android

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development and need some pointers around the input.  I am familiar with the use of Android and I would like to know how to complete general actions around the keyboard.

I know how to set it to things such as phone, email, decimal, and so on.

But how do you change it to move to the next field or fire an action?

Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this `attribute` in `editext` xml  `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone" 
            android:inputType="text"/>
```